# Jenkins is going to shut down when server is down

Tags: windows, jenkins, automated-tests

I have installed Jenkins as standalone in a server. But due to security policy of the company,  server(wherever Jenkins is running) will be shutting down or restarting automatically after 24 hours. So Jenkins instance which is running in command line inside the server is also closing.

So Jenkins is becoming down

Creating a task scheduler to run Jenkins through command line is not helping since i'm  running test automation scripts where the chrome browser is not opening if i schedule a task.

Jenkins is executing internally, Console is running for Web services. What it is executing on Web browser is not showing, as it didn't launch browser.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! :) Your first two paragraphs were clear to me but i could not understand much after that. All i can guess is that you want to see Jenkins running whenever your server is running. If that's the case, you should install Jenkins as a [service](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins). Anyone who is reading your question will only make guess as to which OS your server is running on. So, while posting your question, always provide details such as OS (Win/Linux etc), Jenkins version and any other relevant details. :)

Comment: Thanks @Technext its windows server. The problem if i install jenkins as a service is it will not open chrome browser when i run test automation scripts. As i need to see the browser running to verify the applications functionality. Please suggest

Comment: [JENKINS-52896](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-52896) seems to be what you've mentioned.